# Compare converted (deleted and created) file with git

Tags: java, git, kotlin, refactoring, diff

I do a lot of conversions from Java to Kotlin. Reviewing pull requests with lots of such conversions is difficult, because git does not recognise that the deletion of Example.java 'belongs' to creation Example.kt. This means I have to look at the deleted file's diff in one window and at the newly created file in another window.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to put get a side by side view, preferably using the git command line. Since the languages in my case, Java an Kotlin, have quite some differences, git might not be able to align converted lines to each other. However, this question is more generic: can a side by side diff be shown to compare two different files? Let's say that at commit A we have Example.java and that commit B converts it from Java to Kotlin into Example.kt.

As a bonus, can this side by side diff align converted lines for Java to Kotlin conversions? I guess this not an easy task, because the diff tool would need to have some understanding of what's going on on the language level (not just on the source file level character differences) and compare those similar parts side by side. But who knows, maybe somebody knows a way to achieve this?

Comment: The Git CLI does not itself do side-by-side comparisons: `git diff` shows unified diff format only. However, you can use any other diff tool to compare any two commits. This tool can do whatever it wants—but generally they *still* match up by file name, so you'll need one that (a) does side by side comparisons (e.g., vimdiff) and (b) allows you to specify the input file names (e.g., vimdiff). (I don't actually *use* vimdiff, but it can do the job.)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to generate the pairs on any reasonably up-to-date system:

```
git diff --name-status --diff-filter=AD @~| awk -F$'\t' '
        BEGIN { AD["A"]["/"]; AD["D"]["//"] }
        { base=$2; sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",base); AD[$1][base]=$2 }
        END {   for ( k in AD["D"] )
                        if ( AD["A"][k] )
                                print AD["D"][k]"\t"AD["A"][k]
        }'
```

The BEGIN line just sets up `AD` as an array of arrays with mismatched ersatz base names, the `sub` line remembers added and deleted files by basename, and the END block prints out matching-basename pairs.

On linux anyway it's easy to spit commands to inspect the pairs,

```
# (the above, just printing the right commands:)
git diff --name-status --diff-filter=AD @~| awk -F$'\t' '
        BEGIN { AD["A"]["/"]; AD["D"]["//"] }
        { base=$2; sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",base); AD[$1][base]=$2; }
        END {   for ( k in AD["D"] )
                        if ( AD["A"][k] )
                                print "vim -O <(git show @~:"AD["D"][k]")\t"AD["A"][k]
        }'
```

and pick the pairs you want to inspect.

You can fairly easily get Git to run its diffs on arbitrarily-converted text, hunt up "Git textconv", but I think getting any synchronizer to work backwards from the rendered text to the originals that produced it would be a project.